# mapviz: No transform between /wgs84 to odom

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running robot_localization with an IMU and a GPS. I can visualize the pose estimation it in mapviz and it looks good. Now I want to set the plug-in *Tile_map* (with MapQuest) but i am having this error message "No transform between /wgs84 and odom" and i am not sure what to do.

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234269/mapviz:-no-transform-between-/wgs84-to-odom/) by [fandrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/26822/fandrade/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-05-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I "solved" it by using

```
rosrun swri_transform_util initialize_origin.py
```

I said "solved" because my tf tree looks weird  (it is not a tree).

It looks like:

```
imu_link -> base_link
far_field -> origin
              -> far_field_identity
map -> map_identity
odom
```

---

Originally posted by [fandrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/26822/fandrade/) with karma: 81 on 2016-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1